# Stuck with provider integration with sqflite in a flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, sqflite

I'm trying to implement the provider pattern but i'm struggling in integrating it with a sqflite database. The ChangeNotifier class gets a list of string from the db and then displays it with a ListView. I suppose the problem is that when the ListView builds the widget the ChangeNotifier class has not yet initialised the list so the app crashes. How can i solve this ?

```
class FavouritesProvider with ChangeNotifier {
 
  List<String> _favourites;
 
  List<String> get favourites => [..._favourites];
 
  FavouritesProvider() {
    fetchAndSetFav();
  }
 
  Future<void> fetchAndSetFav() async {
    final data = await DBHelper.instance.getFavourites();
    _favourites = data;
  }
 
}
 
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => FavouritesProvider(),
      child: Container (
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            end: Alignment.topCenter,
            colors: [
              Colors.blue[200],
              Colors.blue
            ],
            stops: [0.0,1]
          )
        ),
        child: Consumer<FavouritesProvider>(
          builder: (context, favouritesProvider, child) => ListView.builder (
                itemCount: favouritesProvider.favourites.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                    width: double.maxFinite,
                    child: FavouritePositionWidget(key: new Key(index.toString()), streetName: favouritesProvider.favourites[index])
                  );
                },
          )
        )
      )
      )
    );
  }
```

But I get this error

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Consumer<FavouritesProvider>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<FavouritesProvider>]):
The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: iterator
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you can't both create and use a provider in the same build method. A common practice is to create the providers at the very top of the tree.

From the provider [example](https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example) :

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    /// Providers are above [MyApp] instead of inside it, so that tests
    /// can use [MyApp] while mocking the providers
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Counter()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```